# Getting error after site restore

Tags: sharepoint-online

On server we have created new web application and restored the content database using stsadm command.
Restoration got successfully completed but when we try to open site using browser we get below error

An error occurred during the processing of . The event handler 'onmenuitemdatabound' is not allowed in this page.

Anyone pls help...

Answer (score 2):

Append ?contents=1 to the end of the URL for the homepage. Close all custom webparts and try again.

If that doesn't work, try deleting suspect webparts.

If that *still* doesn't work, open the site in SharePoint Designer, go to the 'Master Pages' section, right click 'v4.master', and set it as the default master.

Still stuck? Go to /_layouts/settings.aspx, and disable any custom site features.

edit: you have tagged this with "SharePoint Online" - are you using Office 365?